# Checking dates with object oriented programming

Tags: java, date

This is what my lab requires me to do.

Write the class, Date, in the file Date.java according to the following requirements:

1) Instance variables:
month, day, year – all are type, int, all are private

2) Constructors:
Only one that accepts three integers: month, day and year (in that order
-- Throw the exception, IllegalArgumentException, if the three parameters do NOT form a consistent
date object, i.e., an invalid date. An invalid date might:
• have a month, day, or year that is less than 1
• have a month greater than 12
• have a day greater than 31 for months 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
• have a day greater than 30 for months 4, 6, 9, 11
• have a day greater than 28 for February in a non-leap year
• have a day greater than 29 for February in a leap year
NB: A year is leap if it is divisible by 4 and not by 100, unless it is also divisible by 400
For example, 1900 is NOT leap, but 2000 IS leap.

3) Full set of accessors and mutators:
• int getMonth(), int getDay, int getYear()
• void setMonth( int m ), void setDay( int d ), void setYear( int y )
– if a mutator will make a Date object inconsistent (invalid),
the exception, IllegalArgumentException, should be thrown.

4) The method, toString, to return a string that shows the date in the form: MMM-DD-YYYY
Examples: JAN-07-2011 NOV-26-2014 FEB-29-2012 JUN-04-1992

5) Not specified, but needed: You will probably want some private methods to help with validating parts of the
date and determining if a year is leap.

This is the code for lab 13.

```
public class Lab13 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Date d1 =  new Date( 11, 24, 2013 );
   String dateStr = "" + d1;
   if (!dateStr.equals("NOV-24-2013"))
      System.out.println( "ERROR: toString not returning NOV-24-2013 but instead: " + dateStr );

   if ( d1.getMonth() != Date.NOV )
      System.out.println( "ERROR: getMonth not returning NOV but instead: " + d1.getMonth() );

   if ( d1.getDay() != 24 )
      System.out.println( "ERROR: getDay not returning 24 but instead: " + d1.getDay() );

   if ( d1.getYear() != 2013 )
      System.out.println( "ERROR: getYear not returning 2013 but instead: " + d1.getYear() );

   d1.setMonth(12);
   d1.setDay(25);
   d1.setYear(2014);
   dateStr = ""+d1;
   if (!dateStr.equals("DEC-25-2014"))
      System.out.println( "ERROR: mutators(or toString) not returning DEC-25-2014 but instead: " + dateStr );

   try {       
      d1 = new Date( 2, 29, 2016 );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {
      System.out.println( "ERROR: Could not set Date to 2/29/2016" );
   }

   try {       
      d1 = new Date( 2, 29, 2000 );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {
      System.out.println( "ERROR: Could not set Date to 2/29/2000" );
   }

   // trying errors:
   Date d2 = null;

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 13, 14, 2015 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for month = 13" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 0, 14, 2015 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for month = 0" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 1, 32, 2015 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for day = 32 in JAN" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 2, 30, 2016 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for day = 30 in Leap FEB" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 2, 29, 1900 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for day = 29 in non-Leap FEB" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 2, 29, 2014 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for day = 29 in non-Leap FEB" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 4, 31, 2015 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for day = 31 in APR" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 8, 0, 2012 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for day = 0" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   try {
      d2 = new Date( 8, 15, 0 );
      System.out.println( "ERROR: SHOULD HAVE thrown exception for year = 0" );
   } catch( IllegalArgumentException iae ) {}

   System.out.println("No output above means GREAT Date class!!");
}

}
```

This is the code i have written so far for Date.java

```
public class Date {
private int month;
private int day;
private int year;
public static void check (){
  int m = getMonth(m);
  int y = getYear(y);
  int d = getDay(d);
}
public static void getMonth(int m){
  if (m >= 1 && m <= 12) {
     m = month;
  } else {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Date not between 1 and 12");
  }
}
public static void getYear(int y) {
  if (y >= 1) {
     y = year;
  } else { 
     throw IllegalArgumentException("Year can not be less than 1");
  }
}
public static void getDay (int d) {
  if (d >= 1 && day <= 31 ) {
     d = day;
  }else if (d < 30 && month == 4|| month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
     throw IllegalArgumentException("day can not be greater than 30");
  }else if (d < 28 && month == 2 && (year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 != 0) ||
        (year % 4 != 0) && (year % 100 != 0) && (year % 400 != 0)) {
     throw IllegalArgumentException("February can not have over 28 days in non leap year");
  }else if ( d < 29 && month == 2 && (year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
     throw IllegalArgumentException("February can not have over 29 days in a leap year");
  }
}
}
```

The problem I am having is with my instance variables, and trying to get them to accept the number from the lab 13 class.  And of course if anyone can point out anything else im doing wrong especially with how im finding the correct day that would be great. I usually ask my teacher these questions, and most of the time he gets right back to me but its been 3 days and i really need some help with this.

Comment: I would start by creating a constructor in the Date class that satisfies this line from Lab13: `Date d1 =  new Date( 11, 24, 2013 )`.

Comment: So like if i put Date d1 = new date (); into my date class

Comment: No. That's creating an object of the Date class. You need a constructor like `Date(int month, int day, int year)` in your Date class. This might be helpful: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/constructors.html

Comment: ohh alright so its more like if i was passing parameters to a method.